# operation on a value not working (operation > array > control)

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, while-loop

```
int[] subject = { 0, Maths, English, Construction, IT };  

int t = 1;
int c = 0;

while (t < 4)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Chart[c].Text) != 0)
    {
        if (c < 12)
        {
            c++;
        }                       
        Counter();
    }
    else
    {
        int m = random.Next(1, 4);
        Chart[c].Text = Convert.ToString(m);
        subject[m]--; // this isnt working!!
        Chart[c].Refresh();
        tbTotal--;
    }
}
   private void Counter()
    {
        if(Maths == 0 && math == false)
        {
            math = true;
            t++;
        }
        if (English == 0 && english == false)
        {
            english = true;
            t++;
        }
        if(IT == 0 && it == false)
        {
            it = true;
            t++;
        }
        if(Construction == 0 && construction == false)
        {
            construction = true;
            t++;
        }
```

the variable "m" is not being subtracted to allow for the escape of the while loop and limit the addition of values to the textboxes.

the subject use isnt being recording meaning, this means that the if staements arent applicable. because the subject never reaches 0.

This creates an infinite while loop and freezes.

Comment: Where are you increment `t` therefore `subject[t] < 4` is always `true`

Comment: Counter() has basic if statements that switch and increment when the within array subject turns to 0 which is controlled by "subject[m]--;"

Comment: Explain how `subject[t]` AKA `subject[1]` will ever be greater than 4?

Comment: ammended, i didnt see that thanks, it doesnt fix the problem however , that the values within the array arent being subtracted by 1.
i tried stepping and "subject[m]--;" just gets ignored

Comment: `while (t < 4)` will never leave the loop since `t` is always equal to 1.

Comment: i have a function below that i use iterate t using an if statement to ensure that the subject has been filled the required amount of times, however "subject[m]--;" is not working, therefore so the iteration of the subjects is not being recorded

Comment: Your code is frustrating.  What is the scope of `t`?  It looks like it only belongs to the code with the while-loop, but it magically reappears in the Counter function.  What are the values of "Maths, English, Construction, IT" ?  To get good help requires you to post code that can duplicate the problem for us.

Comment: sorry if the code is confusing, im pretty new to coding and the block is 60 lines, and the input box complains i have too much code.
the values of the subjects will be user entered that i assign from textboxes for use within arrays for the while loop and t is just an internal counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you expect this line:

```
subject[m]--; // this isnt working!!
```

to change the original variables `Math`, `English`, `Construction`, and `IT` used to initialize the array, so that later on you will have different results from the `if()` conditional blocks in the `Counter()` method which look at those variables.

That won't happen. The items in the `subject` array are **just values**. Once assigned to the array, *there is no relationship to the variables anymore.*

You can see it play out with this code sample:

```
int foo = 1;
int[] bar = {foo};

Console.WriteLine(bar[0]); // 1 -- initialing the value worked

bar[0] = 2;
Console.WriteLine(foo); // still 1 -- changing the array doesn't change the variable

foo = 3; 
Console.WriteLine(bar[0]); // still 2 -- changing the variable doesn't change the array
```

This might be different if the integers where properties of objects, where you had references for the same object. Then changing the property would change both variables, because they referred to the same object. But simple value types like integer don't work that way.

Instead, I might define my array like this:

```
const int MATH = 0;
const int ENGLISH = 1;
const int CONSTRUCTION = 2;
const int IT = 3;

int[] subjects = new int[4];
```

And now **always** reference the values using a pattern like this:

```
subjects[MATH] = ...;
```

Or you could define a class type like this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Value {get;set;} = 0;
    public bool Dirty {get;set;} = false;
}
```

Then your code might change to use the new class like this:

```
//change old variables to use the new type
var Maths = new Subject();
var English = new Subject();
var Construction = new Subject();
var IT = new Subject();

Subject[] subjects = {null, Maths, English, Construction, IT};

int t = 1;
int c = 0;

while (t < 4)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Chart[c].Text) != 0)
    {
        if (c < 12)
        {
            c++;
        }                       
        Counter();
    }
    else
    {
        int m = random.Next(1, 4);
        Chart[c].Text = Convert.ToString(m);
        subject[m].Value--; 
        Chart[c].Refresh();
        tbTotal--;
    }
}

private void Counter()
{
    if(Maths.Value == 0 && !Maths.Dirty)
    {
        Maths.Dirty = true;
        t++;
    }
    if (English.Value == 0 && !English.Dirty)
    {
        English.Dirty = true;
        t++;
    }
    if(IT.Value == 0 && !IT.Dirty)
    {
        IT.Dirty = true;
        t++;
    }
    if(Construction.Value == 0 && !Construction.Dirty)
    {
        Construction.Dirty = true;
        t++;
    }
}
```

Even better, since these are all references to the same variables, with the same type, you can further change the code like this:

```
var Maths = new Subject();
var English = new Subject();
var Construction = new Subject();
var IT = new Subject();

Subject[] subjects = {null, Maths, English, Construction, IT};

int t = 1;
int c = 0;

while (t < 4)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(Chart[c].Text) != 0)
    {
        if (c < 12)
        {
            c++;
        }                       
        Counter(subjects);
    }
    else
    {
        int m = random.Next(1, 4);
        Chart[c].Text = Convert.ToString(m);
        subject[m].Value--; 
        Chart[c].Refresh();
        tbTotal--;
    }
}

private void Counter(IEnumerable<Subject> subjects)
{
    foreach(var s in subjects.Where(s => s is object))
    {
       if (s.Value == 0 && !s.Dirty)
       {
           s.Dirty = true;
           t++;
       {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i might just change the exit condition of the while loop though.
to exit once the last chart textbox has been changed, its messier and less flexible but simpler.